# How to transform the current user office add-ins installation for all users

Tags: visual-studio, ms-word, vsto

I have found a nice add-in for Word 2013 (VSTO) and I installed it from an admin account, but it doesn't show up in the other local account.

How can I transform the installation for the local user only into installation for all users?

Answer (score 0):

Copy the keys from [HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office\Word\Addins\*YourAddinName*] to [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Office\Word\AddIns\*YourAddinName*]

Answer (score 0):

**Best practice**

Ask this question to the developer

**Custom Installer**

Try [Total Uninstaller](https://www.martau.com/) or my preferred [ESET SysInspector](https://www.eset.com/int/support/sysinspector/) which is free

You will take snapshots of PC before and after installing your addin. Then you compare and get the new created files, new registry entries ... then you convert that for **ALL USERS** and package that in either **Windows Installer** (WIX or Installshield) either **NSIS** or a simple Winform program which will work as an installer.

**NOTE**. I recommend you to contact the addin developer because he is the only one who know what happen during the installation (perhaps also the antivirus :D)